# Probability of a Poisson random variable taking a specific value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> Let $X$ be a random variable with Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda=9$.
>
> Knowing that $P(X=8)=0.131756$, compute $P(X=9)$.

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{e^{-9} 9^9}{9!} = \frac{e^{-9} 9^8 * 9}{8! * 9} $$

Comment: NB: The question title is no replacement for the actual question, wich should be asked in the body.

Comment: It seems to me the variety of answers shows this is not such a simple question. Given that OP did not grasp the point immediately, I'm not sure what OP could have said other than to write the Poisson PDF. Searchable title sort of requires knowing the answer. Hoping for reopening.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if a Poisson random variable $X$ has an integer mean $\lambda \ge 1$, then $$P(X = \lambda) = P(X = \lambda - 1).$$ 
Because

$$P(X = \lambda) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{ \lambda^\lambda}{\lambda !} = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{\lambda-1}}{(\lambda -1)!} = P(X = \lambda -1).$$

The problem is for the case $\lambda = 9.$
Also, these two adjacent values are the 'double' mode of the distribution. (That is, they are the two most likely values of $X$.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$P(X=k\  |\ \lambda) = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$$
We are interested when $\lambda = 9$, and $k = 9$, so just plug them in...
$$P(X=9\ |\ \lambda = 9) = \frac{9^9}{9!}e^{-9} = \frac{9^8}{8!}e^{-9}$$
I believe the info they gave you about $P(X=8) = \dots$ is a red herring, but if you feel it must be used... notice that
$$P(X=k\  |\ \lambda) = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda} = \frac{\lambda}{k}\left(\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}e^{-\lambda}\right) = \frac{\lambda}{k}P(X=k-1\ |\ \lambda)$$
So
$$P(X = 9\ |\ \lambda = 9) = P(X = 8\ |\ \lambda = 9)$$

Answer (score 1):

The knowledge of $\mathbb P(X=8)$ is not actually needed. Since $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(9)$, we have

$$\mathbb P(X=9) = \frac{e^{-9}9^9}{9!} = \frac{4782969}{4480}e^{-9}\approx 0.131756. $$

However, as @Nitin pointed out, it just so happens that $$\frac{e^{-9}9^9}{9!} = \frac{e^{-9}9^8}{8!},$$ so $\mathbb P(X=9)=\mathbb P(X=8)$. So I would assume that is the intention of this exercise.

Comment: Nice direct answ, but puzzled a bit. Did you mean to say 'knowledge of value of P(X = 8) NOT actually needed'?

Comment: That is correct.